# Question about compact sets in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: integration, compactness

Suppose I am given a function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and I'm asked to show that

$ \int_K f(x) \,dx < \infty$ for any compact set $K \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Would it be enough to only consider the closed bounded intervals $[a,b]$? Would then prove it for all compact sets $K$?

Comment: You need some extra conditions on $f$ for this to be true (example, $f(x) = 1_{(0,\infty)} (x) {1 \over x}$ on $[0,1]$). You can suppose $K \subset [a,b]$.

Comment: I know what $f$ is ... my question is, if I proved that it holds for all such bounded and closed intervals $[a,b]$, would it then be true for all compact sets in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Ok thanks... So I take an arbitrary compact $K$ and say there are $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $K \subset [a,b]$ ?

Comment: What kind of integrals are you considering? Riemann or Lebegue?

Comment: The question is a bit vague. If you are talking about the Lebesgue integral, then to say that $\int_K f < \infty$ tacitly implies $\int_K|f| < \infty$, and if you show the result is true on any interval, then it will clearly hold on any subset.

Comment: I suppose the function might be continuous.

Comment: Yeah I meant the Lebesgue integral...